# How to use IF Statement in Formula field for checkbox

Tags: formula, picklist, formula-field

I want to copy data from one field in another if checkbox is true, I know I can do it by trigger but I want to do it in formula field, I don't know how to check the checkbox field my code is like this

```
IF (
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL( Lease_Lease_Assign_Applicable__c, "Yes" ),
        Lease_Assignment_Received__c
    ),
    "Yes",
    "NA"
)
```

Answer (score 6):

if I understood ur requirement correctly, you want to pass the value of the picklist field Lease_Lease_Assign_Applicable__c into a formula text field if the checkbox is checked... the below formula should do it..

```
IF(
  Lease_Assignment_Received__c,
  TEXT(Lease_Lease_Assign_Applicable__c),
  'NA'
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE @Vasmi.  Good to see you over here, seen you for a long time on the answers community.  Welcome :)

Comment: Thanks @sfdc_ninja .. u guys r doing an awesome job here :-)